# QMenu change background color

Tags: qt

I'm trying to change the background color of a `QMenu*` object it does not work with `setStyleSheet()`, nor with `setPalette()`.

I read [this article](https://forum.qt.io/topic/25008/solved-background-color-of-qmenu-by-stylesheet-doen-t-work-this/4) but the guy says that I should add this line:

```
app.setStyle(QStyleFactory::create("fusion"));
```

I'm not sure what is `app`, I tried several combinations but it does not work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You probably forgot to set `QMenu`'s parent:

```
#include <QtGui>

class Window : public QWidget
{
public:
    Window(QWidget *parent = 0) : QWidget(parent) {}
    void contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent *event)
    {
        QMenu menu(this);
        menu.addAction(new QAction("Item 1", this));
        menu.addAction(new QAction("Item 2", this));
        menu.exec(event->pos());
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    Window *window = new Window;
    window->setStyleSheet("QMenu::item:selected { background-color: green; }");
    window->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

[image]